# how can i solve ESLint error that 'no-unused-var' with google map

Tags: javascript, html

**I think that it's simple problem but i can't solve it**
I had entered `/* export myMap */` or `/* global myMap */`  at the top of the script but errors is continuing

## Code

#### HTML

```
<h1>My First Google Map</h1>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:60%;height:600px;margin: auto;"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function myMap() {
    var mapProp= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(37.540881, 127.079689),
        zoom:17,
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
```

When I wrote the code as showed above, I saw the following error

> Error ESLint  'myMap' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)
> Error ESLint  'google' is not defined. (no-undef)
> Error ESLint  'map' is assigned a value but never used. (no-unused-vars)
> Error ESLint  'google' is not defined. (no-undef)

but google API use 'google', 'map' and I use 'myMap' . it's no doubt
please help beginner. thx

p.s. I don't want solve with `/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */`

Comment: You can remove `var map = ` in front of the `new` to solve the `map is assigned a value but never used.`

Comment: or just `return map` or if you want more testable function `return !!map` so it just returns boolean value

Comment: However you can also put ignore comment `/* eslint-disable-next-line */` and for no-undef eg. `/*global  describe, it, expect*/`

Comment: how can I resolve 'google' and 'myMap' ?

Comment: @JAESEUNGLEE you can only do it by using npm module, otherwise use `/*global describe, it, expect*/` if you mix modules bundle with loaded from web libs.

Comment: @ Zydnar thx!!! but how can I resolve 'myMap' (no-unused-vars)?  I used it with callback in script tag

Comment: If `myMap` is used in a separated file or script tag, then you have to export `myMap` so that the linter knows that it will be used somewhere else. If you don't use any bundler/module system then you need to do it by writing `window.myMap = myMap`

Comment: @Zydnar This can not only be done with npm modules. It can be solved with any packager or modules system, that has a syntax for importing and exporting.

Comment: @ t.niese thx!! error is gone. but I want to know what `window.myMap = myMap` means. Is this just setting 'mymap' as a global variable? and what is mean "use any bundler/module system"? how can i use any bundler/module system for export `function name` like 'myMap'? I want to know detailed answer. thx again :)

Comment: @t.niese you're right, I totally forgot about other posibilities. Also good written answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get rid of the error messages you have to tell your linter that `google` is an external variable, and you need to tell the linter that you plan to use `myMap` externally. And as you don't use `map` later you can just remove the `var map =`.

The linter is really dumb and can only verify the consistency within the file that it currently lints, it cannot verify that use a function in another file/script and it cannot verify that a variable originates from somewhere else.

The simplest approach would be to use the `global` option to tell the linter that `google` was defined somewhere else, and write `window.myMap = myMap`, that way you explicitly assign `myMap` to the global object `window` (which for the given code does not really change anything as `myMap` is already defined globally) and tells the linter that it is expected that is is used somewhere else outside of that script.

The linter cannot verify that `myMap` that it is really used somewhere else and has to trust you there.

```
/* global google */

function myMap() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.540881, 127.079689),
    zoom: 17,
  };
  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}

window.myMap = myMap;
```

But if you don't use a module bundler like webpack or rollup and nothing like commonjs, amd or native es6 modules, then you should always wrap your code into an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to ensure that you pollute the global scope as less as possible:

```
(function() {
  /* global google */

  function myMap() {
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.540881, 127.079689),
      zoom: 17,
    };
    new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  }

  window.myMap = myMap;
}())
```

And here the `window.myMap = myMap` has indeed the purpose to make the function available for other scripts.

Instead of writing `/* global google */` you could do the inverse of the `window.myMap = myMap`, but this will only work if the scripts are loaded in the correct order so that the google maps scripts sets `goolge` before your script executed:

```
(function() {
  var google = window.google;

  function myMap() {
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.540881, 127.079689),
      zoom: 17,
    };
    new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  }

  window.myMap = myMap;
}())
```

Now you have a syntax that is really close to how AMD modules (like used in nodejs or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)) look like, and would make it easier if you plan to switch to a bundler in future:

```
var google = require('google');

function myMap() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.540881, 127.079689),
    zoom: 17,
  };
  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}

exports.myMap = myMap;
```

Comment: `(function() {
  var google = window.google;  

  function myMap() {  
    var mapProp = {  
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.540881, 127.079689),  
      zoom: 17,  
    };  
    new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);  
  }  

  window.myMap = myMap;  
}())`   when I use this code, I can't see my google map. why?

Comment: last code block is working but 3rd code block is not working.

Comment: @JaeseungLee updated the text, the 3rd code block will only work if the scripts are loaded in the correct order and if the script of google initialized the global variable `google` early enough.